# New pandas column for values of list found in previous column

Tags: python, list, dataframe

I have a list.  I have a dataframe column.  I want to iterate through my dataframe column with my list and make a new dataframe column with the corresponding rows based on the values of the list contained in each row of my dataframe column.  The dataframe column are texts_excerpts and the list are the tokens I am wanting to find and keep track of.  Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

@acodejdatam Based on the assumption that you need to count how many words from the list appear in the text_excerpt column, you can try the following code. If this doesn't answer your question, please provide an example so that we can help you better with your question.

```
 sample dataframe (df)
      index         text
  0      1       I am A
  1      2   My name is
  2      3  Who are you

  sample list (l)
  l = ['My', 'is', 'are']

  def find_match(series, l):
      words = series['text'].split()
      found_words = []
      for word in l:
          if word in words:
              found_words.append(word)
      return found_words

  df['words_contained']= df.apply(find_match, args=(l,), axis=1)
```

The answer for the above sample code will modify df to the following

```
Out[16]: 
          index         text      count
          0      1       I am A      []
          1      2   My name is      [My, is]
          2      3  Who are you      [are]
```

Comment: so that is exactly what I am wanting to do, except, I want to have the actual words contained in the series column listed like the below example:  index          text           words_contained
          0      1        I am A               A
          1      2        My name is       My name
          2      3        Who are you     are

Comment: Updated the answer for your question. Please note you just had to change the logic in the find_match function
Also, always add an example to your question for people to help you better :) Good luck

Comment: Thank you so much!

Answer (score 1):

Edit to original question:

so that is exactly what I am wanting to do, except, I want to have the actual words contained in the series column listed like the below example:

```
      index         text      words_contained
      0      1       I am A      ['I']
      1      2   My name is      ['My', 'name']
      2      3  Who are you      ['are', 'you']
```

Answer (score 0):

One more update to the question:

What if instead of the list l = ['My', 'is', 'are'], we had a dictionary like
mydict = {'My':-21,'is':-12,'is':1}.  How would you perform something similar as to above, but add dictionary values with the "scores" added together based on the words from each row.  I would rather append the weight(value from the dictionary) for each key (the word from the dictionary)

I am trying something like this:

```
`def find_match(series, mydict):
words = series['text'].split()
found_words = []
for word in mydict.keys():
    if word in words:
        found_words.append(mydict.value().sum)
return found_words
```

df['words_contained']= df.apply(find_match, args=(l,), axis=1)

I keep getting the error: AttributeError: ("'list' object has no attribute 'keys'", 'occurred at index 0')`

Thanks so much for your help so far.  This has been wonderfully helpful. :)

Comment: What is 'l' that you are passing to the function ?

Comment: Sorry, that is the original list(now a dictionary), that I want to pass.

Comment: that's the  args=(l,), you had put on the original answer, I am actually wondering why that had to be passed in the first place, and only a comma after it... :)

Comment: Read documentation for args here: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html

Also, is it working after changing l to dictionary ? If not please paste the entire code